# Shower Retaining Ring?

Tags: bathroom

I had a ring on my shower before removing it to paint the room.

I placed the ring in a certain area, but our house's friendly ghost aparrantly needed it more and took it.

Needless to say, I still need the ring. What is the name of the ring? I couldn't find it anywhere on Home Depot's website.

Here is a picture after the ring is missing.
[image: Missing Ring]

Comment: it is not a retaining ring .... it is just a cover to make it look pretty

Comment: @jsotola I'm aware, I just didn't know what to call it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that it's commonly called a Shower Arm [Escutcheon](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS827US827&biw=1492&bih=721&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=_Hw2XNm_FeGFggeRgpKoDQ&q=shower+arm+escutcheon&oq=shower+arm+es&gs_l=img.1.0.0j0i24.5163.5664..7310...0.0..0.69.132.2......1....1..gws-wiz-img.......0i5i30j0i8i30.NA-TPYOVXhM) or [Flange](https://www.google.com/search?q=shower+arm+flange&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS827US827&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv14qp5uHfAhUhnuAKHY54CKcQsAR6BAgAEAE&biw=1492&bih=721).
[image]

Comment: They also make them with a pivot so you don't have to pull things apart but they are more expensive. +